# Where is Android app title in settings configured?

Tags: android, settings, title

We have an existing app about to release an update for; however, the update has changed the title of the app when seen in Settings/Apps.

**Is that based on a setting in console (e.g. one of the titles we set there), or is it configured in the manifest / build?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the `manifest.xml` and under the `application` tag you must have this attribute:

```
android:label="myapplicationname"
```

You can change it there. 
It's common practice to keep the app's name/title in `strings.xml`:

```
<string name="app_name">myapplicationname</string>
```

and in the manifest keep a reference to it:

```
android:label="@string/app_name"
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: I'm glad it helped.